# What is the difference between "at all times" and "at any particular time"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time

Morrison writes in "Morrison, Michael A. : Understanding quantum physics : a user's manual"

> $ |\Psi(x,t)|^2 \xrightarrow[x\rightarrow\pm \infty ]{} 0$    at all
>   times *t*  [bound state]
>
> $ |\Psi(x,t)|^2 \xrightarrow[x\rightarrow\pm \infty ]{} 0$   at any
>   particular time *t*  [unbound state]

So I can imagine that "all" means the entirety of all times, but do I not get "all" when summing over all particular states?

I also understand that in a bound state, the wave is never at the infinity position, but the wave of an unbound state may exist there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the book M.A. Morrison, *Understanding quantum physics: a user's manual,* but it seems that 
the phrase

> *at all times $t$*

is used in the sense that the $x$-limit is

> *[uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) in $t\in\mathbb{R}$,*

while the phrase

> *at any particular time $t$*

is used in the sense that the $x$-limit is

> *[pointwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) in $t\in\mathbb{R}$.*

In other words, the difference is in the ordering of pertinent [quantifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification). Note that Morrison's above terminology is not standard.

Comment: This is surely right, but one could clarify by saying that a nonuniform limit happens when a bump is travelling to infinity without spreading out. This doesn't happen in the Schrodinger equation, so he could have been less careful.